# Read list on remote client SharePoint server from SQL server or code

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

My need is to query the SharePoint lists maintained on a client's server in order to update related information in our project management and tracking system. I would like to query the SharePoint list directly, since so far the only method I have is to manually export the list from the SharePoint session into an Excel spreadsheet, and then access the Excel Spreadsheet from other tools on my side, or use MS Access to read from the SharePoint site and then propagate the data from Access. I can read the SharePoint server, but I do not have any access or authority to modify anything on it. The results I obtain need to be distributed to some database updates on my side, and then to Excel spreadsheets, dashboards and reports.

I can do crude versions of some of this using MS Access to read from SharePoint, but I run into common problems such as truncated text, missing data from text fields and other garbled data coming across due to Access limitations. Fields from text boxes on the SharePoint side that come across HTML formatted are a particular issue, as some rows will contain data, but the same field in some rows come across as null, despite the source on the SharePoint side having data. MS Access then does not give accurate results. Automation is also more difficult through MS Access.

All of that said, I would like to be able to read-only some columns from the SharePoint list programmatically from SQL using an SQL server on my side or something similar.

Several articles and posts here on Stack Overflow have indicated that this is basically impossible. Some other articles have hinted that there is a way to do this, but might require me to modify things on the SharePoint side. I cannot make any modifications to the SharePoint server in this instance.

Comment: Never used Access before, but you can use Excel 2016 Get & Transform(Power Query) to get data from SharePoint library, then output the result in your worksheet. And you can carry on from there.

Comment: Have you tried using the API?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: Can you open the SharePoint site on the client's site from a browser on your SQL server, or from another machine on your network? If so, you can access list data using custom app via the SharePoint REST API, or from PowerShell. Let us know if this works, and what version of SharePoint they are using.1

Comment: We recently updated out Office 365. The version of MS Access and MS Excel that I am using now have integrated Power Query, which allows me to do what I need to do. I have tried, as was suggested, connecting to the SP server from an SQL Server image running on my side, but have not yet been successful. That would be an even better solution than Power Query. Thanks for the suggestions, they did help me to resolve this.